# Lighting changes when loading scene

Tags: unity, lighting

I have a script that changes the levels using

```
Application.LoadLevel (sceneNameToChangeTo);
```

Once a level is loaded using that code when testing with the editor, the lighting changes dramatically. I've checked if something changes in the light or lighting settings, but it doesn't.

This is a screen of how the scene looks when I simply press RUN in the scene in the editor:

[image: correct lighting]

Notice the blue tints from the sky etc. This is clearly PBS lighting.

Now after I use my code to change the scene to another one and then back to this one, the scene looks like this:

[image: bad lighting]

What am I doing wrong? I am using Unity 5.0.1. This effect does not happen on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem as well. I believe it is due to using the editor that unity doesn't load it as quickly and as a result not all the shaders are implemented or not all the lighting that is baked is configured.

All I can suggest is wait for a fix. In the meantime it does not actually affect the project when you build it, and when testing you should build it often to check how it works as it should.(just grin and bear it until unity make a fix)