# Baked lightmaps in SceneA, at runtime loaded SceneB from SceneA: lighting is now messed up in untouched SceneB. Only in Editor!

Tags: unity, lighting, lightmap

I'm using **Unity**, and in my **MainMenu scene** I made most objects **static** and **baked some lightmaps**.

I **built** the game, clicked on a button in **MainMenu** which `SceneManager.LoadScene` the **SceneB**, and everything works as expected.

However **in the Editor**:

- I start the **MainMenu** scene,
- click on the button,
- **SceneB** loads up, and the **lighting is messy**.

If I just **directly start SceneB** the scene looks **as it should**.

Why? How could I fix this?

They got their **separate LightingSettings**, **MainMenu** got its **LightingData** lightmap, and when I `LoadScene` **SceneB**, lightmap becomes **None**. But it looks **darker**, more **yellow/orange**.

[image]

I also tried unloading unused resources, but nothing changed.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
```

Comment: We have a couple of [past questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/101204/39518) about [this issue](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/198695/39518). Does the suggestion at that second link of [deleting and re-assigning your lighting settings](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/198699/39518) work for you?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for the suggestion but deleting, reseting, restarting, etc, then starting it all over again didn't fix it. :\

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? Have you tried updating to the latest version of your engine branch?

Comment: @Kevin Not yet. But I think it's pretty recent and I haven't seen recent posts about this issue, so I don't think it's a Unity issue. I use 2021.3.30f. I'm only 3 minor patches behind.

Comment: @Tudvari The release notes for 2021.3.31f1 include this: "Fixed bug where Directional Lightmaps would sometimes contain degenerate values when baking scenes with lots of invalid lightmap texels." It's worth upgrading to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks a lot, will do! :)